# In an integration test, using the test helper `triggerKeyEvent` on an input inside a `<form>` does not submit the `<form>`

Tags: ember.js

This question is based on the demo repo https://github.com/bartocc/so-enter-key-integration-test

This demo Ember.js 3.12 app contains the `<XFoo>` component. When rendered, it displays a simple `<form>` with a text input and a submit button.

The `<form>` has an action bound on its `submit` event that will set the component's `submitted` property to `true`. By default, it is `false`.

The desired behaviour is to display a thank you message instead of the `<form>` after submitting it.

Here is the component's template:

```html
{{#if this.submitted}}
  <span>
    Thank you for your submission
  </span>
{{else}}
  <form {{action (mut this.submitted) true on="submit"}}>
    {{! template-lint-disable self-closing-void-elements }}
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">
      Save
    </button>
  </form>
{{/if}}
```

I've added 2 integration tests for `<XFoo>`:

- one tries to send the `Enter` keydown event to the `<input>` tag with the code

```js
await render(hbs`<XFoo />`);
await triggerKeyEvent('input', 'keydown', 'Enter');
```

- the other clicks the submit button with

```js
await render(hbs`<XFoo />`);
await click('button');
```

Both tests check the presence of the thank you message with:

```js
assert.dom('span').hasText('Thank you for your submission', 'displays the thank you span');
```

The first test fails, the second one passes.

I would like to understand why using `triggerKeyEvent` does not submit the form.

Comment: Does actually pressing Enter submit the form when running the application?

Comment: Yes, it works when running the app

Comment: @bort on Discord suggested that this might be related to the following `ember-test-helpers` issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/issues/626. And I believe that indeed, I've hit the same limitation.

Comment: Seems like it should work since it is an example in the docs: . Have you tried using the keycode instead? `await triggerKeyEvent('input', 'keydown', 13);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trigger it by using the native event dispatcher:

```js
const submitForm = async (element) => {
  const submitEvent = new Event('submit');
  element.querySelector('form').dispatchEvent(submitEvent);
  await settled();
};
```

I call this after filling the content of the input

```js
await fillIn(selector, '<content>');
await submitForm(this.element);
```

Comment: This doesn't do implicit form submission -- note that you're explicitly triggering the form submit here, by dispatching the submit event from the `form` tag. Additionally, if I try to use it, I end up with a perpetual test as the default form behavior (navigate to page) is invoked, rather than my `{{on "submit" ...}}` handler that disables bubbling & prevents default, etc.